# debugging rails apps, is the debugger keyword the only way? any IDE help?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

is the only way to debug a rails app is to use the 'debugger' keyword and then start the server with the debugger switch?

are there any IDE's that make this more traditional where you can trace line by line?

Answer (score 1):

I think NetBeans is able to do this. Probably also the more ruby centric editors and ides.

Answer (score 1):

Try radrails:
http://www.aptana.com/products/radrails